# SELECT without FROM? Leetcode #176

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql. One of the answers of this problem I found is

```
select (select distinct salary from Employee order by salary desc limit 1,1) as SecondHighestSalary
```

Why can it be written as this without FROM?
This problem requires to return null value if there is no second highest salary.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases allow a query without a `from`.  A typical example is something like this:

```
 select 1 as n;
```

In this case, the second `select` is a *scalar subquery*.  It is a subquery that returns one column and at most one row, so it is treated as a literal value in the expression.

However, because the query is only selecting one column, the two `select`s are not needed and it is simpler to write:

```
select distinct salary as SecondHighestSalary
from Employee
order by salary desc
limit 1, 1;
```

However, this will not return any values if there is only one salary in the table.

Comment: the subquery is needed to return null (rather than no rows) when all salaries are the same or there are no rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> SELECT can also be used to retrieve rows computed without reference to any table.
> ...
> You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced:
> ...
> DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced.

So if you are more comfortable, or you need to use some query-building library that requires a table name, you can say:

```
select (select distinct salary from Employee order by salary desc limit 1,1) as SecondHighestSalary
from dual;
```

but it is completely optional.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please tell me why if there is only one SELECT, then it will return an empty result, but if I add one more SELECT and it will return a null row?

Comment: when you use a subquery as one of the select expressions (or in other cases like `where (select ...) = 42`), it always needs to return a single value.  if your select expression returns multiple columns or multiple rows, you will get an error.  if it returns 0 rows, it will produce the value `null`.